# Routing Error during "Ruby on Rails-Tutorial"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

It seems like some people here had this problem but I couldn't find any solution in another topic.

I am doing Chapter 3 of the Ruby on Rails-Tutorial, working on the static pages. When I want to open them on the localhost it gives me a "Routing Error" in the Browser.

My Ruby is currently on version 1.9.3.
My Rails is currently on version 3.2.

I have tried:

- restarting the server
- saving all the files again
- checking any issues in the static_pages_controller.rb
- checking any issues in the routes.rb
- checking any issues in the static_oages_spec.rb

Also there are no bugs in the HTML code of the single static page. And I can't find any more help in the tutorial, neither in other questions here on StackOverflow.

---

Edit:

This is the actual error message from the browser:

> Routing Error
>
> No route matches [GET] "/static_pages/home" Try running
> rake routes for more information on available routes.

if I go to `http://localhost:3000/static_pages/home`, to one of three static pages I have.

This is routes.rb:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  
get "static_pages/home"

get "static_pages/help"

get "static_pages/about"

end
```

Also, I tried "`rake routes`" in the terminal, too. This is the result:

```
home_static_pages GET    /static_pages/home(.:format)  static_pages#home
 help_static_pages GET    /static_pages/help(.:format)  static_pages#help
about_static_pages GET    /static_pages/about(.:format) static_pages#about
      static_pages POST   /static_pages(.:format)       static_pages#create
  new_static_pages GET    /static_pages/new(.:format)   static_pages#new
 edit_static_pages GET    /static_pages/edit(.:format)  static_pages#edit
                   GET    /static_pages(.:format)       static_pages#show
                   PUT    /static_pages(.:format)       static_pages#update
                   DELETE /static_pages(.:format)       static_pages#destroy
```

And this is the error message the server is giving me:

```
Started GET "/static_pages/home.html" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-03 13:23:54 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/static_pages/home.html"):
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /Network/Servers/pluto.kayoom.lan/Users/benediktkrebs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Network/Servers/pluto.kayoom.lan/Users/benediktkrebs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Network/Servers/pluto.kayoom.lan/Users/benediktkrebs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: If you add the actual error message people may be able to help you.

Comment: Also add the exact URL you are trying to load, and your routes file please.

Comment: Can you push your full current (not working) code to github? That would make it easier for people to find out what/where the problem is.

Comment: Yeah, but I found the problem anyway... ;)


I am at the very beginning of that stuff... =D

My Rails Server was running in the .../rails_projects/demo_app.
Currently I am working in the sample_app.

Thanks for the nice answers anyway... =D Hope I made you laugh shortly... ;)

Comment: just paste your controller and let us see your controller class and methods, the routes that have been specified below should work if you have matching controller methods

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
match "/static_pages/home" => "static_pages#home", :via => :get
match "/static_pages/help" => "static_pages#help", :via => :get
match "/static_pages/about" => "static_pages#about", :via => :get
```

Add into routes , restart the server and refresh browser .

Comment: Did exactly the way you said... Doesn't help, too. Sorry! =( Updated the question above a bit more.

Comment: Try to run 'rake routes > route.txt' . And check your routes into the file . And try that.

Comment: The routes in the text file are exactly the ones I have in the route.rb. Without any spelling error.

Comment: weird ... may be some platform issue

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Spork you must re-run Spork so your tests will consider the changes in config files like routes.rb, that are pre-loaded with Spork, so are not automatically updated.

1. Stop Spork (Ctrl + C)
2. Run Spork again (bundle exec spork)

Source: [this is the source of this information](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#code%3arspec_drb)
"after changing a file included in the prefork loading (such as **routes.rb**), you will have to **restart the Spork server to load the new Rails environment**. 
If your tests are failing when you think they should be passing, quit the Spork server with Control-C and restart it

Answer (score 0):

your routes.rb file has problems, use either RESTful style:

```
resource :static_pages do 
  collection do 
    get :home
    get :help
    get :about
  end 
end
```

or the non RESTful style:

```
match "static_pages/home", :controller => "static_pages", :action => "home"
match "static_pages/help", :controller => "static_pages", :action => "help"
match "static_pages/about", :controller => "static_pages", :action => "about"
```

for more details please refer to official guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Tried both. sadly it doesn't help... I still exactly the same error message. Also after restarting the Server and also after saving the file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a few problems working through the Rails Tutorial, and it helped to be able to consult the author's GitHub repo: https://github.com/railstutorial

Find the file you're working on and compare it line by line. Or just cut and paste the full file and see if it will run, then track down your error.

Comment: Same problem again. Searched for the routes.rb in his github, copied into my file and saved. Restarted server and refreshed browser. Still the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the routes.rb in config you'll probably find that the there is a 'e' missing from /home. Add that and you are golden. Or green. Or whatever :)

Answer (score 0):

check your http:// address, specifically if you are on localhost:3000/path or localhost:3000/path1/path2, etc

Answer (score 0):

Once you change the format of your mapping from `get` to `match` you will not need static_pages anymore, just go straight to `localhost:3000/pagename` e.g `localhost:3000/about`

Answer (score -1):

From Ruby 2 to Ruby 3 there are some differences, but still the documentation for 3 is not easy to be found. There should be a tutorial only for that: practical differences between rails 2 and 3.
The guide provided by downloading Ruby on rails is "The book of ruby" but it's not good anymore. It should at least contain an advice at the beginning of chapter 19.

Answer (score -1):

In

config/routes.rb

uncomment

## root :to => 'welcome#index'